# Disable subviews isHighlighted from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have images inside of a UITableViewCell, I was using the "isHighlighted" field to set if the image should be gray or colored. Whenever I select the cell, the UITableViewCell sets isHighlighted to true on all subviews, is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are overloading isHighlighted to do some custom logic like how to present the cells when they are not selected.

If so, it would be better to subclass UITableViewCell and add your custom property to the subclass instead of using 'isHighlighted' and use the derived class in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass with `self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` and then override `setHighlighted:animated:`:.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated{
     [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
     // Set your imageView background color here
}
```

Note that `UIImageView` does not inherit from `UIControl` and so it has no `highlighted` property.  However, `UITableViewCell` does try to set its subviews' background colors to transparent when it is highlighted.  You may not be able to control the background color behavior of the built in `imageView` via `setHighlighted...`, in which case you would want to add your own `UIImageView` which you control completely.